# How to brake network capabilities of an apk? Not installed app

Tags: android-studio, apk, networkx

Am trying to disable all network capabilities of an app. I know how to do it in settings but i want to brake all online service of an app on apk. so that even if i share apk of that app with someone else they won't have to disable network of that app manually. I am slightly familiar with Android studio and java.

Answer (score 0):

Try lucky patcher app. It's not available on Play store.

Comment: ya i tried to rebuild APK using lucky patcher but ahe app crashes at startup
even disabling one permission makes the app crash on startup

Comment: It's a LUCKY patcher :-)